# Separate a comma separated value in an array list then put it back together

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, separator

What I am trying to do exactly is creating a sorting program that sorts PatientRecords by whatever the user specifies in the command-line.

The program is operated on command-line and the user will input a text file containing the records as the first argument (args[0]), and how he wants it sorted as the second argument(args[1]).

The text file is formatted as: `Lastname, Firstname, Age, Roomnumber` for each line.

The amount of Lines is not specified and can vary, therefore I am using an Array list.

I can read in the lines and I got to where I could sort it by last name, but it looks like to me that the only way to do it is by separating the line at the commas and apprehending them individually in separate methods.

If there is a better way please let me know, I am open to anything.  My main problem is getting the program to sort by the different categories, such as Age or RoomNumber.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PatientRecord 
{

      public static void main(String args[]) {
         System.out.println("Servando Hernandez");
         System.out.println("Patient sorting Program.");

         Scanner scan = null;
         try
         {
            scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
         } 
         catch (FileNotFoundException e)
         {
             System.err.println("File path \"" + args[0] + "\" not found.");
             System.exit(0);
         }

         ArrayList<String> lines=new ArrayList<String>();

         while(scan.hasNextLine())
             lines.add(scan.nextLine());

         if(!(args.length == 0))
         {
             if(args[1] == lastname)
             {
                 sortByLastName();
             }
             else if(args[1] == firstname)
             {
                 sortByLastName();
             }
             else if(args[1] == age)
             {
                sortByAge();
             } 
             else if(args[1] == roomnumber)
             {
                 sortByRoomNumber();
             }
         }

      }
      static String sortByLastName()
      {
          Collections.sort(lines);

         for(String x : lines)
             System.out.println(x);
      }

      static String sortByFirstName()
      {

      }

      static int sortByAge()
      {

      }

      static int sortByRoomNumber()
      {

      }
 }
```

Comment: You are asking a number of questions here. They can all be answered very easily if you **abandon your `Object` phobia**.  Read the file into object, sort those object then write those objects.

Comment: Simple ans yes ! What you are doing will be very tedious to maintain. You should create a class and fill data into it. Then create a list of that class and write a custom comparator for sorting. Then implement toString method in that class so you can convert hem back to a string format the way you like.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a model class named `Patient` which has firstName, lastName etc.

  ```
  class Patient{
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   // Constructor, getter, setter
  }
  ```
- I guess, text file line are comma separated. So, split the line into array and populate the List

  ```
  List<Parent> patients= new ArrayList<>();
  while(sc.hanNextLine()){
  String[] values= sc.nextLine().split(",");

   patients.add(new Patient(...))
  }
  ```
- Now, read the customer preferences from command line and sort the patients List.

  ```
  String sortType= sc.next()

  switch(sortType)){//Use java 7 or greater for string switch
    case "firsname":
    //Now sort the list by firstname using Comparator sort method.
    break;
    case "lastname":
    ....
  }
  ```

Comment: In this case a `switch` would be more readable than `.equals` + `else if`